# Xamarin Forms. Keyboard on android covers bottom of an entry with custom background

Tags: xamarin, background, xamarin.forms, renderer, xamarin.forms.entry

I use an entry in XF with custom background for Android platform. When it is focused the keyboard covers bottom line of entry.

```
public class MessageEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement != null || this.Element == null)
            return;

        Control.Gravity = DefaultGravity;

        var MessageEntry = Element as MessageEntry;
        UpdateBackground(MessageEntry);
        ...            
    }

private void UpdateBackground(MessageEntry MessageEntry)
    {
        if (_renderer != null)
        {
            _renderer.Dispose();
            _renderer = null;
        }
        _renderer = new BorderRenderer();
        //Set to background object of type GradientDrawable
        Control.SetBackground(_renderer.GetBorderBackground(MessageEntry.BorderColor, MessageEntry.BackgroundColor, MessageEntry.BorderWidth, MessageEntry.BorderRadius));
    } }
```

Pictures:
[Entry with borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLUHZ.png)
[Keyboard covers bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQG2P.png)
    I need to show bottom line. I tried to add padding like this:
    `private void UpdatePadding(MessageEntry MessageEntry)
            {            Control.SetPadding((int)Forms.Context.ToPixels(MessageEntry.LeftPadding), 10,
                    (int)Forms.Context.ToPixels(MessageEntry.RightPadding), 0);

            }`
But it is padding for text inside entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.
The problem was with padding for entry. It was 0 for bottom and top. I set it as shown in following code:

```
private void UpdatePadding(MessageEntry MessageEntry)
    {
        Control.SetPadding((int)Forms.Context.ToPixels(MessageEntry.LeftPadding), Control.PaddingTop/3,
            (int)Forms.Context.ToPixels(MessageEntry.RightPadding), Control.PaddingTop/3);
    }
```